DS-160 - Employment details for long retired person (B1/B2)
I'm trying to fill the DS-160 form for a B1/B2 visa for my father, who retired 20 years ago. Are the employment details needed for him?
I'm not sure if the interpretation is — “while he was employed, give the final 5 years of the employment details”.
He can’t seem to remember the details as he had moved 4 jobs in between that year.


Probably fill the last employment if you could it will help and provide dates of the employment
